# Can't find my installed application (VPython)

Tags: python, visualization

I am using Ubuntu 10.4 and just installed VPython but could not find it to run. In the software center, its showing that it is installed. I tried Alt+F2 but it says could not open location. Can anyone help me with it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run `VPython` in a Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

VPython is a Python 2 library, to be imported in a python script. You cannot run it as a standalone application, but you can use it for example in combination with IDLE (using python 2).

There is good information & examples on how to use it [here](http://www.vpython.org/), [here](http://www.youtube.com/user/VPythonVideos)( youtube movies) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPython)

[image]

Comment: No module named visual error.

Comment: did you install vpython? the above picture is from my desktop, just installed it. it is python2 btw

Comment: how to install vpython?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I did it from the software center.